# How To Get Rotation Data Printed Every Frame

Tags: scripting

What would the script be to get the rotation of a cube printed after every frame?

Comment: Can you show some of your work in a Blender screen capture with a text editor window?

Comment: Please see related on the right side of this web page.

Answer (score 1):

**Using a frame change handler**

> [Application Handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.handlers.html#module-bpy.app.handlers)
>
> This module contains callback lists

Test script.  After (post) a frame change, print the local euler rotation of the cube in degrees.

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

def cube_rot_report(scene):
    cube = scene.objects.get("Cube")
    if cube:
        #rot = cube.matrix_world.to_euler()
        rot = cube.rotation_euler
        print([degrees(r) for r in rot])

#clear the handlers
#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(cube_rot_report)
```